# i5 6th generation drivers are available in ubuntu 16.4

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, ubuntu-drivers

I want to upgrade my system with Intel i5 6th generation,8gb ram.
but my question is that if I install Ubuntu 16.04 64bit so all systems drivers are available default in it. (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question specifically, but upgrading to 16.04 also upgraded all systems drivers automatically when I did it.

Comment: Question is not clear, specify if:
1) You already have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on your HDD and are upgrading your  hardware and expecting it to work.

OR

2) Will Ubuntu 16.04 work on install with the new hardware??

Comment: This is not an answer, but I personally run 16.04 on an i5-6200U CPU and it works well.

Comment: yes option 2 I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 with new hardware.(i5 6th genration)
so i want to be clear that ubuntu is supported the hardware?(means all hardware drivers are default taken by ubuntu)

Comment: i5 is obviously supported. Other drivers have to do with other hardware only which is independent of the CPU.